# Удаление изображений с сервера php

Tags: php, сервер, изображения

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как удалять изображения с сервера если их в базе уже нет, если я их удалил?

Comment: А можете подробнее описать как храните изображения, регистрируете их в базе данных?

Comment: В базе хранится имя изображения. Я его на сервер загружаю и в базу.

Comment: Изображение на сервер

Comment: Все файлы хранятся в одной папке? Трудно получить их полный список для сравнения с содержимым в базе данных?

Comment: В одной папке, да. Я вот так пытаюсь удалить:

Comment: $result3 = pg_query("SELECT * FROM realestate where coalesce(picture,'')!= ''"); 

    while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result3)){
       
        $file = $row['picture']; 
  
     if(!file_exists($file)){
        unlink($file); 
     }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы сделал так:

- получаем через функцию [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) список всего что есть в нашей директории с файлами (часть кода позаимствовал [здесь](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php#87527))

  ```
  $truedir = <путь_к_директории>;
  $dir = scandir($truedir);`
  ```
- чистим от вложенных, маркера текущей и родительской директорий:

  ```
  foreach($dir as $k => $v) {
      if ((is_dir($truedir.$dir[$k])) || $dir[$k] == '.' || $dir[$k] == '..') {
          unset($dir[$k]);
      }
  }
  $dir = array_values($dir);
  ```
- потом перебираем все эти файлы, и проверяем, если данного имени в нашей таблице с файлами нет (просто проверяем запросом количество найденных соответствий - если 0) - удаляем файл через [unlink](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)